# What should be done to get around or resolve the PrimeFaces exception requiring the definition of a lazy attribute or one that doesn't result in null?

Tags: primefaces

I am in the progress of upgrading a legacy application from PrimeFaces 6.2 to 11.0.0 (which is the newest available with maven - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces). I have had to make a number of changes, including adding Object as the parameter for RowEditEvent and TreeNode objects (which are now generic) and changing instantiations of DefaultStreamedContent to use .builder(). Now, I am facing the following error whenever I try to run the application and navigate to certain pages:

"javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to automatically determine the `lazy` attribute. Either define the `lazy` attribute on the component or make sure the `value` attribute doesn't resolve to `null`."

It looks like an exception is being thrown rather than a warning as is noted in the conversation here: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8436. It also looks like it was fixed, but for version 12 (which is not on the maven central repository).

I am wondering what my options are, or what could be done about this. Should I go back to an older version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround you could create an application factory which sets the `lazy` attribute to `false`.

See: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/core/globalattributes

Answer (score 4):

Is it a lazy DataTable which uses LazyDataModel? If yes, just set `lazy=true`, otherwhise set `lazy=false`