# Primefaces 13 How to avoid the warning "Unable to automatically determine the `lazy` attribute, fallback to false."

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using PF 13.0.3. I have this warning on UITable "Unable to automatically determine the `lazy` attribute, fallback to false. Either define the `lazy` attribute on the component or make sure the `value` attribute doesn't resolve to `null`. clientId: tblOrderlines]]"
It's only a warning, but it would be better to avoid them.

I followed the tip of Jasper de Vries

[What should be done to get around or resolve the PrimeFaces exception requiring the definition of a lazy attribute or one that doesn't result in null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72566106/what-should-be-done-to-get-around-or-resolve-the-primefaces-exception-requiring)

by setting a global attribute lazy=true on UITable as explained in https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/core/globalattributes

```java
if (component instanceof UITable){
    component.getAttributes().put("lazy", true);
}
```

But now I see this warning for practical all the components except for the UITable

Even if I set this outside the if-block, those multiple warnings doesn't disappear.

Should I return to an earlier version of PF?

Any tip is appreciated, thanks

After reading the tip of BalusC to return an empty collection:
I use many tables of which a great number initially is empty and will only get filled with data if and only if
the user undertakes an action. This tip could result in creation of many useless empty collections if the user never undertakes an action.
Returning `Collections.emptyList()` isn't advisable because this collection is immutable.

Perhaps I should create a custom `ListDataModel` and add a method to test, depending on the expected data that could populate the table, whether `getWrappedData()` should return  `Collections.emptyList()` or `new ArrayList()` instead of null

Comment: Just don't return `null` when collection is empty, but an empty collection. Conform standard Java collections coding conventions. See also among others https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1168/

Comment: Perhaps this tip could result in creation of many useless empty collections ? I have supplemented the original question with my reflections

Comment: use Collections.emptyList then ;)

Comment: @tandraschko Collections.emptyList() is immutable - see my reflections in the updated question

Comment: Whats the problem with return an immutable list, if your data is null?

Comment: @tandraschko the data can initially be null but the user should in partically cases, be able to add data. If data can be added, then new ArrayList() otherwise Collections.emptyList().

Comment: why not just make your getter "return data == null ? Collections.emptyList : data" and init your data when the user press e.g. a "add" button?

Comment: @tandraschko, not a good idea, getter can be called from .xhtml for many times and even if data == null, doesn't mean that Collections.emptyList() is the best returnvalue. I prefer either lazy = 'true to every JTable or subclass ListdataModel